# Laravel Retrieve and Validate Multiple Inputs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for suggestions on the best route to accomplish this task.

After a user registers, they are taken to a menu with 2 steps. The first step is to select from a list of checkboxes (this is all set up and works), then based on which checkboxes they select, on the 2nd step they have an array of text inputs to enter in keywords like so.

If they checked the "games" checkbox, this will show up.

```
<input type="text" name="gameInfo[]" class="form-control input-global"/>
<input type="text" name="gameInfo[]" class="form-control input-global"/>
```

If they choose the "art" checkbox, this will show up.

```
<input type="text" name="artInfo[]" class="form-control input-global"/>
<input type="text" name="artInfo[]" class="form-control input-global"/>
```

So, there can be multiple text inputs for different arrays. The goal is to take whatever is in the text inputs and save it to my pivot table that also brings in the user_id and the type_id (which relates to games, art, etc.). The pivot table is all ready to go, I just created an additional column (type_details) to take these text inputs.

Here is my controller. I am thinking I can use the following, but that checks if it's there AND not blank. If the user submits a blank form, the "has" won't catch it.

```
if ($request->has('gameInfo')
{ // code here }
```

If I can use this type of logic for each of the arrays (gameInfo, artInfo, etc.), I think that'd solve the problem, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Controller:

```
$gameInfo = Input::get('gameInfo');
$artInfo = Input::get('artInfo');
$musicInfo = Input::get('musicInfo');
$buildingStuffInfo = Input::get('buildingStuffInfo');
$educationalInfo = Input::get('educationalInfo');

if ($request->has($gameInfo))
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'gameInfo' => 'required',
    ], [
        'required' => 'You must enter information on the games.',
    ]);
}

if ($request->has($artInfo))
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'artInfo' => 'required',
    ], [
        'required' => 'You must enter information on the art.',
    ]); 
}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Instead, I'm going to put the input names like so.

```
<input type="text" name="typeDetails[games]" class="form-control input-global"/>
<input type="text" name="typeDetails[art]" class="form-control input-global"/>
```

JS:

```
var data = { 'typeDetails[games]' : [], 'typeDetails[art]' : [] };

$("input[name='typeDetails[games]']").each(function() {
    data['typeDetails[games]'].push($(this).val());
}); 

$("input[name='typeDetails[art]']").each(function() {
    data['typeDetails[art]'].push($(this).val());
});
```

However, in my controller, it only grabs the 'games' portion of the array and doesn't continue to check for the 'art' portion.

```
$typeDetails = Input::get('typeDetails');            

if ($request->has('typeDetails.games'))
{
    return 'games';
}

if ($request->has('typeDetails.art'))
{
    return 'art';
}
```

Comment: those are arrays so in the validation it should be `gameInfo.*` https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays, also if the user is going to have to use one of the 3 info (game,art,music) in that case u can use a variable and then call it in the validation to avoid the duplication in code.

Comment: Please have a look at this link : http://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/

What you are trying to validate is an array and it should be handled in a different way.

Comment: And as suggested in the link, it would be advisable to move the validations from the controller to the Requests class. That would make your controller less cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'gameInfo.*' => 'sometimes|array',
    'artInfo.*' => 'sometimes|array',
    // etc 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use standard Laravel way? Just use [custom Request class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation) for each form to validate and `fill()` class to fill model with all validated inputs at once.

Validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|unique|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users' 
    ];
}
```

Filling after validation:

```
$info = new Info();
$info->fill($request->all());
```